# Change background on click and skip first element in board

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I just wrote a simple script to change background on click and the problem is second repeat when the first element in board is omitted here's my code

```
$(function() {
    var i = 0;
    var preloadImg = [
        'https://www.colourbox.com/preview/11903964-black-and-white-embossed-paper-background-lighting-effect.jpg',
        'http://download.4-designer.com/files/20140222/Personalized-lobes-mosaic-background-vector-material-57935.jpg',
        'http://www.tabletwallpapers.org/download/peak-wallpaper_800x800.png',
        'https://s29.postimg.org/51x27g4dj/save_world_colo2r.jpg'
    ];

    $(".right").click(function() {
        if (i < preloadImg.length) {
            $('.back').css('background-image', 'url(' + preloadImg[i] + ')');
        } else if (i == preloadImg.length) {
            i = 0;        
        }
        i++;
    });
});
```

Here is the : [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ux5a8e0o/10/)

Comment: You are setting `i = 0;`, and then you increase i again afterwards with `i++;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can try this one:

```
$(".right").click(function(){               
      if(i==preloadImg.length){
         i = 0;
      }
      $('.back').css('background-image', 'url(' + preloadImg[i] + ')');
      i++;
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tomjerry25/ux5a8e0o/15/)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
$(function() {

  var i = 0;
  var preloadImg = ['http://www.tabletwallpapers.org/download/peak-wallpaper_800x800.png','https://www.colourbox.com/preview/11903964-black-and-white-embossed-paper-background-lighting-effect.jpg','http://download.4-designer.com/files/20140222/Personalized-lobes-mosaic-background-vector-material-57935.jpg','https://s29.postimg.org/51x27g4dj/save_world_colo2r.jpg'];

  $(".right").click(function() {

    if(i<preloadImg.length) {
      $('.back').css('background-image', 'url(' + preloadImg[i] + ')');
      i++;
      if(i==preloadImg.length) {
        i = 0;  
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I entirely understand what you're saying, but if it's the case that you're missing the first image after a full loop, there are a few ways to fix it, the easiest is just to set your image in the else part...

https://jsfiddle.net/ux5a8e0o/12/

```
    if (i < preloadImg.length) {
      $('.back').css('background-image', 'url(' + preloadImg[i] + ')');

    } else if (i == preloadImg.length) {
      i = 0;
      $('.back').css('background-image', 'url(' + preloadImg[i] + ')');
    }
    i++;
```

There are more elegant ways however...